# How can i extend the code to be able to show drop list of values from selected column in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm new to sql and i'm trying to create SSRS.
I found this code in internet to create SSRS report and it works good to me. However i need to adjust this code to get the value as well from selected column

```
USE [project]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Report]    Script Date: 26-1-2020 01:19:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Report]
@SchemaName VARCHAR(128)='sys',
@TableName VARCHAR(128)='columns',
@ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)='object_id,column_id,name,max_length,system_type_id'

AS 
BEGIN 


DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @ColumnNamesVAR VARCHAR(MAX)

--drop ##Temp_Data Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Temp_Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Temp_Data


    --drop ##Temp_Data_Final Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Temp_Data_Final') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Temp_Data_Final

--drop #Temp_Columns Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp_Columns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp_Columns

Create table #ColumnList (Data NVARCHAR(MAX))
insert into #ColumnList values (@ColumnList)

--convert all column list to VARCHAR(1000) for unpivot

;with Cte_ColumnList as (
SELECT 
'['+LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)')))+']'  AS ColumnList
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Data,',','</RowData><RowData>') 
+ '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   #ColumnList
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n))
,CTE_ColumnListVarchar  as
(Select 'CAST('+ColumnList+' as VARCHAR(1000)) AS '+ColumnList AS ColumnListVAR,ColumnList from Cte_ColumnList)

SELECT @ColumnNamesVAR = COALESCE(@ColumnNamesVAR + ', ', '') + ColumnListVAR,
@ColumnNames = COALESCE(@ColumnNames + ', ', '') + ColumnList 
FROM  CTE_ColumnListVarchar

--Insert data into ##Temp_Data Table
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TempTbleSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TempTbleSQL='Select ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (order by (Select 1)) AS R,'+@ColumnNames +' into ##Temp_Data from ['+@SchemaName+'].['+@TableName+']'

--Print @TempTbleSQL
EXEC(@TempTbleSQL)

SET @SQL='

select 
R,columnname,value into ##Temp_Data_Final from 
(select R,'+@ColumnNamesVAR+' from ##Temp_Data )u
unpivot
(value for columnname  in ('+@ColumnNames+'))v'
--Print @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)

Select * From ##Temp_Data_Final

END
```

SO, Now i can select Schema, Table & column. but i couldn't know how i get drop list for values in selected column. 
And one more thing. how i can deploy this report to web form.Or if there any way to create dynamic sql with cascading parameters where i can select schema, table, column and values
PLEASE SOMEBODY HELP ME WITH THIS IT REALLY IMPORTANT

Here i can choose Schema, then table and the column. So i want to extend the code to be able to get another drop list with value of selected column 
[image]

I used also the following datasets for each parameter

```
--ds_schema 
SELECT NAME AS schemaname FROM sys.schemas
WHERE NAME not in (
'guest',
'information_schema',
'sys',
'db_owner',
'db_accessadmin',
'db_securityadmin',
'db_ddladmin',
'db_backupoperator',
'db_datareader',
'db_datawriter',
'db_denydatareader',
'db_denydatawriter')


----DSTables
Select Distinct Table_Name as TableName from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA=@SchemaName
order by Table_Name



----DS_Columns
Select COLUMN_NAME as ColumnName from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA=@SchemaName
and TABLE_NAME=@TableName
```

[image: Her]

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Maybe regarding to my bad english, but the question is: How can i extend the code to be able to show drop list of values from selected column.

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you want to achieve. Sketch out the report layout, include what you expect to see in each parameter, some sample data where applicable and the final expected output.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield, Here i added screenshot of my report. and dataset for each parameter. In the report design i used MARTIX so: (R for rows, value for data, columnname for column)

Comment: OK, so you have your cascading parameters done. I'm not sure what you actually want to see in your report though? It's not clear what part you cannot do.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, what i can do now is: choose the Schema, after that i get tables and finally select the column list. What i want to do more is after i select one column i can get list with all values in that column

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of values in a column you need to build a SQL statement then execute it.

As you have your parameters you can do something like this...

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

**notes**

- This gives a DISTINCT list of values and also sorts them using the ORDER BY clause, just edit the `SET @SQL =` line to adjust the query that is executed.
- I've used QUOTENAME() to put square brackets around the schema, table and column names e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT [myColumnName] FROM .....`
- You can add `PRINT @SQL` at the end to see the generated SQL if you like.

Comment: Thanks. but i think we need to include this statement in our SP_Report. because as you see in the SP the values were inserted in temp table then it was selected from it

Comment: You really need to show what your final output should look like, you asked how to get a list of values and that is what I explained.Edit your question to show the expected final output and I'll take a look tonight

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Alan , I added screenshot. So let say i selected this columns from my table. Now i need to get i list of values from those columns so i can filter based on them. so i don't need all rows. i just need rows for specific contract number (for example)